# What constitutes 'no activity' for power-saving modes?

Tags: windows-xp, electrical-power

Does anyone know what conditions have to occur for Windows to keep a PC out of power-saving actions such as monitor/disk shut-down, hibernation, etc?

I want to run a build script which could take a while, when I leave, and have the PC shut down after it ends but not risk hibernating part-way through.

Comment: Are you subject to Group Policy restrictions?

Comment: I don't think so, if I understand what that means. I have admin rights on my workstation and can change power saving settings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Normally "activity" means input from keyboard or mouse. Depending a a variety of things, such as how the driver is written, some other forms of input may also be considered to be activity. Things like disk I/O is not activity in this context. There are a number of ways to fool the OS into thinking there is activity but it is ussually simpler to just disable hibernation temporarily and have your build script call for a shutdown when it's done. You can use shutdown.exe for that.